# javaFX: showSaveDialog() not saving file with correct extension

Tags: javafx, filechooser

I have created small java Program using javafx. in which i'm trying to save any text file or java file. **it save file on expected location but without extension** this might be the silly question but i don't have any experience with javaFX,

**1.Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**2.Controller.java**

```
 package sample;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
     private TextArea TextArea;
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    void OnButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Java files (*.java)", "*.java");

        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(selectedFile != null){
            SaveFile(TextArea.getText(), selectedFile);



        }
    }
    private void SaveFile(String content, File file){
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter;

            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(content);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }
}
```

**3.sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="269.0" layoutY="275.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OnButtonClicked" text="Save" />
      <TextArea fx:id="TextArea" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I'm currently new to JavaFx and java technology,  help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The filter in the FileChooser is only for filtering existing files in the active folder. If you want to add a default file extension you need something like:

```
String fileName = file.toString();
if (!fileName.endsWith(".java"))
fileName += ".java";
```